# how do convert json string to a string

Tags: json

I have the `json` string from MySQL database:

```
{"teams":[{"sport":"NFL"},{"sport":"NBA"},{"sport":"NCAA Football"},{"sport":"NCAA Men Basketball"}],"success":1}
```

And I need to convert this string to the following format:

```
 final String sports[] = {"NFL", "NBA", "NCAA Football", "NCAA Men Basketball"};
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Plenty of ideas ... not many clues

Comment: a trick would be to use a regex like this : "sport":"([A-Za-z\s]*)" the capture group is exactly the sport word

Comment: Take a [look at jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it is a general parser/editor for json and can be utilized for all manner of json transformations.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.json.*;
String jsonString = yourJsonStringFromDatabase;
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray team = obj.getJSONArray("teams");
String[] sports = new String[team.length());
for (int i = 0; i < team.length(); i++)
{
    sports[i] = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("sport");
}
```